# Как выполнить три потока последовательно

Tags: java, многопоточность

Всем привет, задача вот такая в общем: есть класс Foo и 3 метода, нужно создать три потока, каждый из которых вызывает по одному методу, и создать так, чтобы они последовательно написали "firstsecondthird"

```
class Foo{
    private static final Semaphore printOne = new Semaphore(1);
    private static final Semaphore printTwo = new Semaphore(1);
    private static final Semaphore printThree = new Semaphore(1);

    public Foo() throws InterruptedException {
        printTwo.acquire();
        printThree.acquire();
    }

    public void printFirst() throws InterruptedException {
        printOne.acquire();
        System.out.print("first");
        printTwo.release();
    }
    public void printSecond() throws InterruptedException {
        printTwo.acquire();
        System.out.print("second");
        printThree.release();
    }
    public void printThird() throws InterruptedException {
        printThree.acquire();
        System.out.print("third");
        printOne.release();
    }

}

public class Starter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new Thread(new Thread1()).start();
        new Thread(new Thread2()).start();
        new Thread(new Thread3()).start();
    }
}
class Thread1 implements Runnable{

         @Override
         public void run() {
             try {
                 new Foo().printFirst();
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
}
class Thread2 implements Runnable{

         @Override
         public void run() {
             try {
                 new Foo().printSecond();
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
}
class Thread3 implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                new Foo().printThird();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

Данный код успевает создает только один поток Thread1 и печатает "first", а дальше бесконечно ожидает. Не могу понять почему это происходит и как это исправить.
PS может, как-то получше можно написать, чтобы поток вызывал один метод в классе Foo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем коде ошибка возникает потому, что семафоры статические, и захватываются в конструкторе класса `Foo`. А создаете вы три экземпляра этого класса. По-этому, первый экземпляр создается нормально, а два других вызова конструктора блокируются и до вызовов метода `print` дело не доходит.

Исправить можно, либо сделав захват семафоров тоже статическим:

```
  static {
      try {
        printTwo.acquire();
        printThree.acquire();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
  }

  public Foo() throws InterruptedException {
  }
```

Либо создавать один экземпляр класса `Foo` и передавать его в конструкторы `Thread1` и т.д.

Еще одни вариант, это использовать `CountDownLatch`. Он не требует предварительного захвата. Поток, который дошел до точки синхронизации сообщает об этом другому потоку:

```
    static CountDownLatch firstFinished = new CountDownLatch(1);
    
    public void printFirst() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.print("first");
        firstFinished.countDown();
    }
    public void printSecond() throws InterruptedException {
        firstFinished.await();
        System.out.print("second");
        secondFinished.countDown();
    }
```

Но лучше, конечно, не накладывать статические блокировки в нестатических методах. Семафоры (или `CountDownLatch`-и) лучше сделать нестатическими и работать с одним экземпляром `Foo` во всех потоках:

```
public class Starter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        new Thread(new Thread1(foo)).start();
        new Thread(new Thread2(foo)).start();
        new Thread(new Thread3(foo)).start();
    }
}
class Thread1 implements Runnable{
    private Foo foo;
    public Thread1(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
             foo.printFirst();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вот как раз таки я сделал статистические блоки, потому как не понимаю, как сделать так, чтобы разные потоки работали с одним экземпляром класса, ведь, если создать объект класса Foo в main, то он будет виден только классу Starter. Как поменять структуру или как сделать так, чтобы можно было работать с одним объектом класса Foo во всех потоках?

Comment: @Tunix добавил пример